# ¿Por qué no se muestra los datos del array bidimensional?

Tags: array, c

Estoy teniendo un problema raro en mi código, hice esto repetidas veces pero ahora no se que pasa y no me deja imprimir el array.

El código es el siguiente

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MESES 12
    
void cargarNombreYApellido (char nombre[100]);
void crearContrasenia (char nombre[100], char password[200]);
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(int cantEmpresas);
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]);
void mostrarVector(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]);
    
//#############################################################
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
     
    int cantEmpresas = elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(cantEmpresas);
    int empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
    cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]);
    return 0;
}
//##############################################################
    
    
   
/*Elegir con cuantas empresas quiere trabajar el usuario, menor a 3*/
    
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(int cantEmpresas)
{
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
    return cantEmpresas;
    //agregar problema al añadir 3 empresas o mas
}
    
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i,k;
    
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++)
        {
            empresas[i][k]=rand()%11;
        }
    }
}
    
void mostrarVector(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i;
    int k;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++)
        {
            printf("%f  - ", empresas[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Si yo borro el `printf` donde intento imprimir el array, la consola retorna en valor 0, pero claramente no me muestra mi array.
Cuando yo pongo:

```
printf("%f  - ", empresas[i][k]);
```

La consola no solo que no imprime nada, si no que retorna en un valor muy extraño.

Comment: Si te esta imprimiendo valores sin sentido, entoces estas tocando memoria que no es tuya, revisa los tamaños

Comment: Nono, es que no me imprime nada

Comment: @HatoriHanso al momento de intentar pasar esto: `empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]` ya estás desbordando el búfer, porque las columnas de un array 2D va de 0 a 11 (en este caso claro)

Comment: Y como puedo solucionarlo para que me imprima las columnas?

Comment: Aún no solucionas el problema??

Comment: Hola dave, lamentablemente no, esto me esta carcomiendo la cabeza, no entiendo que esta mal en el codigo como para que este no pueda imprimir los numeros

Comment: @HatoriHanso Te he puesto una respuesta.. Espero te ayude!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Observaciones principales:**

**1.-** No necesitas especificar el nombre del parámetro cuando declaras una función. Por lo tanto, lo puedes hacer así:

```c
void cargarNombreYApellido (char[]);
void crearContrasenia (char[], char[]);
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(void); //El "void" indica que esta función no recibe ningún parámetro.
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int, float[][MESES]);
void mostrarVector(int, float [][MESES]);
```

**2.-** La función `elegirCantidadDeEmpresas` no necesita de un parámetro, debido a que retorna el número de empresas, con eso basta:

```c
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas()
{
    int cantEmpresas; //--> Variable local.
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
    return cantEmpresas;
}
```

**3.-** Estás [desbordando el búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) y esto genera un comportamiento indefinido (puede resultar cualquier cosa en tiempo de ejecución):

```c
cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas,empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]);
```

La primera dimensión representa el tamaño de filas y solo puede recibir índices de `0` a `cantEmpresas - 1` y la segunda dimensión son el tamaño de columnas que va desde `0` a `11`. Entonces no podemos pasarnos de esos límites, de lo contrario, tendrás errores.

Realmente lo que quieres hacer es pasar la dirección de memoria del primer elemento de la matriz para que la función se encargue de rellenar de datos dicha matriz. Por lo tanto, deberías hacer esto:

```c
cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas);
```

El identificador `empresas` no es más que un alias que representa la dirección del primer elemento de la matriz.

**4.-** Sin embargo, aquí hay otro problema, ya que el segundo parámetro solo puede recibir una "matriz" de tipo `float` y usted le está pasando una matriz de tipo `int`, ahí estamos mal, tanto el argumento (en este caso el argumento sería el identificador `empresas)` como el parámetro (en este caso sería `float empresas[][MESES]`) deben ser del mismo tipo.

Así que debemos cambiar la declaración del identificador `empresas` a:

```c
float empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
```

**5.-** Según el estándar la función `main` debe ser definida de esta forma:

```c
int main(void) //--> void indica: "NO ACEPTO PARÁMETROS".
{
     //... code
     return 0;
}
```

Siguiendo estas observaciones podríamos cambiar el código a esto:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MESES 12

/* Declaraciones: */
void cargarNombreYApellido (char[]);
void crearContrasenia (char[], char[]);
int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(void); //Esta función NO ACEPTA PARÁMETROS.
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int, float[][MESES]);
void mostrarVector(int, float [][MESES]);

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int cantEmpresas = elegirCantidadDeEmpresas();
    float empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
    cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas);
    mostrarVector(cantEmpresas, empresas);
    return 0;
}

int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas()
{
    int cantEmpresas;
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
    return cantEmpresas;
}

void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i,k;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < MESES; k++)
            empresas[i][k]= rand()%11;
    }
}

void mostrarVector(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i;
    int k;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++)
            printf("%f  - ", empresas[i][k]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**Observaciones extras:**

**1.-** Esta sentencia:

```c
float empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
```

Se denomina [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length-Arrays), que en español significa *un arreglo con longitud variable*. En el código de arriba la variable `cantEmpresas` vendría ser esa *longitud variable* que se obtiene en tiempo de ejecución.

El problema radica que no todos los compiladores incluyen esta característica, debido a que, es propenso a que ocurra [desbordamiento de pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_pila). Así que por cuestión de portabilidad, no se lo debería usar.

**2.-** La forma segura de hacer esto, sería crear una matriz dinámica. Ahí tocaría crear un *array de punteros* (representaría las filas) y luego reservar memoria otra vez para asignarle la dirección a cada puntero del *array* (todo esto representaría las columnas y así formando una especie de *array bidimensional*). Para más información recomiendo leer este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376010/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-realmente-los-arrays-bidimensionales-din%C3%A1micos-en-c/376118#376118).

**EDIT:**

Para generar números flotantes aleatorios lo podrías hacer de esta manera:

```c
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES])
{
    int i,k;
    float n;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < MESES; k++)
        {
            n = rand() / (float) RAND_MAX; //Genera un rango de (0.0 a 1.0)
            empresas[i][k]= (n * 300) - 100; //Genera un rango de (-100 a 200)
        }
    }
}
```

**Fuente:** [How to generate random float number in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13408990/how-to-generate-random-float-number-in-c#:%7E:text=float%20x%20%3D%20(float)rand,RAND_MAX%5D%20inclusively.).

Comment: Entonces, simplemente mi error estaba en como utilizo los parametros? Nuestro profesor nunca nos explico desbordamiento de pilas, VDA y tampoco nos explico como definir parametros utilizando solamente 
int nombre _(int, float, char[])_

Comment: Tenías dos errores: En el primero estabas declarando una matriz de tipo `int` cuando debería ser de tipo `float` y el segundo es por la forma como pasabas el valor al parámetro. Debías pasar únicamente el identificador `empresas`.

Comment: Gracias dave, y ahora que necesito darle valor de -100 hasta 200, con decimal incluido, como tengo que hacer? Estaba leyendo y vi la palabra reservada "drand48" pero es solo para linux, hay alguna formula especial para asignarles valor con decimal entre esos parametros?

Comment: @HatoriHanso He editado la respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En el código que publicaste hice los siguientes cambios

El primer error esta en esta linea

```c
cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]);
```

Tienes que pasar un `float*[12]`, pero pasas el valor que este en `empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES]`, por eso falla. Tienes que activar los avisos del compilador, asi te enteraras de estos problemas antes de que caigas en errores.

Luego el problema que comentabas, no llamas la función `mostrarVector`, por eso no imprime nada.

Ya aplicando los cambios el y limpiando el codigo queda asi:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MESES 12

int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(void);
void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]);
void mostrarVector(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]);


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int cantEmpresas = elegirCantidadDeEmpresas();
    float empresas[cantEmpresas][MESES];
    cargarMatrizAleatoria(cantEmpresas, empresas);
    mostrarVector(cantEmpresas, empresas);
    return 0;
}

int elegirCantidadDeEmpresas(void){
    int cantEmpresas;
    printf("\n\n\nCon cuantas empresa deseas trabajar? (Menos de tres) \n");
    scanf("%d", &cantEmpresas);
    return cantEmpresas;
}

void cargarMatrizAleatoria(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]){
    int i,k;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++) {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++) {
            empresas[i][k]=rand()%11;
        }
    }
}

void mostrarVector(int cantEmpresas, float empresas[][MESES]){
    int i;
    int k;
    for (i=0; i<cantEmpresas; i++) {
        for (k=0; k<MESES; k++) {
            printf("%f  - ", empresas[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero necesito que los datos sean flotantes, es lo que me pide el enunciado

"Una vez que ya sabemos la cantidad de empresas (y de meses, 12, obvio), generar una matriz de números flotantes aleatorios, entre -100 y 500, estos flotantes tienen que ser con coma, no puede ser todos coma 00. "

Comment: Dejame mejor edito el codigo que puse

Comment: Usa la solución de @Pablochaches que es muy buena y antes de pasar los valores les sumas un valor aleatorio entre 0 y 1 sin incluir los extremos

Comment: Pero necesito que los valores aleatorios sean flotantes, no enteros

Comment: @HatoriHanso Ya le hice el cambio para que sea con `float`. Ahora, que sea entre -100 y 500, ademas de que también sean decimales al azar es tu tarea. Yo no soy tu maestro ni me pagas para que sea tu tutor. Corregi el problema de la pregunta, otros erroes pequeños, y limpie el codigo. Y me vas a pedir mas?.Los cambios para eso hazlos en la funcion `cargarMatrizAleatoria`, lo demas queda a tu creatividad

Comment: Yo nunca pedi ayuda para generar los valores dentro de esos parametros, simplemente necesitaba ayuda para que me muestre la matriz, muchas gracias