# ¿Como ingresar una matriz como parametro a una función si el numero de filas y columnas es n?

Tags: c, funciones, parametros, matriz

He intentado de diversas maneras, pero no encuentro como hacerlo correctamente, debo ingresar una matriz con numero de filas = numero de columnas, pero el valor es ingresado por el usuario. Gracias de antemano

Previamente almaceno el dato ingresado por el usuario

```
printf("Ingrese el tamanio de la matriz:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
```

Y posteriormente almaceno en numero, la funcion realizada con el tamaño de la matriz ingresada por el usuario

```
int numero= funcion(matriz[][n], n);
```

Pero investigando, se supone que la segunda dimension solamente debe estar detallada, sin embargo, no encuentro la manera de ingresar n como segunda dimension en la funcion. Guardo n como segundo parametro, para utilizarlo despues. A continuación lo que tengo en esa línea:

```
int funcion(int **matriz[][tam], int tam){
```

Comment: Por favor, coloca una **versión mínima** del código problemático junto con una descripción del problema (error de compilación, resultados esperados/obtenidos). Tal y como está, parece que estás pidiendo un ejemplo. Y ese tipo de preguntas **no** están permitidas.

Comment: ¿Qué hace `funcion()`? ¿Has pensado en usar un puntero doble?

Comment: @Gabitohh Creo que sobre su uso trata la pregunta :-)

Comment: funcion() retorna el numero mas grande de la matriz ingresada

Comment: Sí el número de filas y columnas se obtendrán en tiempo de ejecución, no queda de otra que crear un [array bidimensional dinámico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376010/c%c3%b3mo-funcionan-realmente-los-arrays-bidimensionales-din%c3%a1micos-en-c/376118#376118). De ahí, si quieres acceder a la matriz por medio de funciones, tocará crear un parámetro, en la cual, sea un puntero doble. Y por cierto, por ninguna razón uses [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length-Array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Como ingresar una matriz como parámetro a una función si el numero de filas y columnas es n?

Usando un doble puntero matas dos pájaros de un tiro:

- Te evitas el problema de los argumentos copia
- Obtienes una matriz *flexible*, ya que puedes hacer uso de memoria dinámica.

> No encuentro la manera de ingresar n como segunda dimensión en la función.

Al ser un doble puntero puedes asignarle memoria dinámica al primer puntero con `malloc()`:

```
int tam;
scanf("%i",&tam);
int *(*matriz) = malloc(sizeof(int*) * tam);
```

Con esto defines a `matriz` como un array de punteros. Después puedes usar el operador `[]` para asignarle nuevamente memoria dinámica a cada puntero del array.

```
void funcion(int *(*matriz),int tam) {
    for (int i = 0;i < tam;i++) matriz[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * tam);
}
```

Después de esto ya tendrías un array de arrays. Aclarar que

*El prototipo de `funcion()`:*

```
void funcion(int *(*matriz),int tam);
```

*El uso de `funcion()`:*

```
funcion(matriz,tam);
```

Donde `matriz` es un doble puntero, con el primer puntero inicializado con memoria dinámica. De esta manera se puede decir que `matriz` es `[n][n]` y `funcion()` recibe `[n][n]`.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto: `int *(*matriz) = malloc(sizeof(int) * tam);` crea un array de enteros. Para crear un array de punteros sería así: `int *(*matriz) = malloc(sizeof(int*) * tam);`

Comment: @MrDave1999 Cierto, error mío. Gracias.