# ¿Por qué no imprime el contenido de la matriz?

Tags: c

Tengo una consulta: En  lenguaje C, estoy tratando de pasar una matriz(array bidimensional) que contiene **strings** como parámetro a una función la cual es `void` y manda a imprimir lo que tiene dicha matriz.

La cuestión es que lleno la matriz y al momento de querer imprimir no me funciona (o sea no me aparece la información que llene).

Aquí les dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Prototipo de la funcion
void Imprimir(char [][30],int);

int main()
{
    int dim;
    printf("Ingrese el numero de elementos que tendra el vector: \n");
    scanf("%d",&dim);
    char vector[dim][30];
    for(int i=0 ; i<dim; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Para la posicion %d ingrese el valor: \n",i+1);
        gets(&vector[i][30]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    Imprimir(vector,dim);
    return 0;
}

//FUNCION IMPRIMIR 
void Imprimir(char v[][30],int tam)
{
    v[tam][30];
    for(int i=0 ; i<tam ; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<30 ; j++)
        {

            printf("%c",v[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias fallas en el programa:

**1.-** Estás desbordando el búfer:

```c
gets(&vector[i][30]);
```

La segunda dimensión solo admite indice de `0` a `29`. Lo que debes hacer es pasar la dirección de memoria del primer elemento de cada array. Ten en cuenta que un **array bidimensional** (*o matriz*) se conforma por **arrays unidimensional**.

**Solución:**

```c
gets(vector[i]);
```

La expresión `vector[i]` devuelve la dirección base de cada *array* que conforme la matriz.

**2.-** No estás detectando la longitud de cada *string*:

```c
for(int i=0 ; i<tam ; i++)
{
     for(int j=0 ; j<30 ; j++)
     {
          printf("%c",v[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

Como verás, el bucle anidado recorre todo el *array* pero el problema es que puede que el *array* no ocupe todas las posiciones, así que posiblemente estarías imprimiendo **caracteres extraños**.

Podrías obtener la longitud de cada *array* por medio de la función `strlen`:

```c
for(int i=0 ; i<tam ; i++)
{
     for(int j=0 ; j < strlen(v[i]); j++)
     {
          printf("%c",v[i][j]);
     }
     printf("\n");
}
```

De igual manera, no hace falta el bucle anidado (así evitamos usar la función `strlen`):

```c
for(int i=0 ; i < tam ; i++)
      printf("%s\n", v[i]);
```

**3.-** Este código no tiene sentido:

```c
v[tam][30];
```

No hace nada, deberías eliminarlo.

Siguiendo con las correcciones, el código quedaría así:

```c
int main()
{
    int dim;
    printf("Ingrese el numero de elementos que tendra el vector: \n");
    scanf("%d",&dim);
    char vector[dim][30];
    for(int i=0 ; i<dim; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Para la posicion %d ingrese el valor: \n",i+1);
        gets(vector[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    Imprimir(vector,dim);
    return 0;
}
 
void Imprimir(char v[][30],int tam)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i < tam ; i++)
        printf("%s\n", v[i]);
}
```

### Observaciones:

**1.-** No uses la función [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) para pedir cadenas. Es insegura, ya que puede provocar un desbordamiento de búfer. Su reemplazo es [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

```c
fgets(vector[i], 30, stdin);
```

**2.-** No uses [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array):

```c
char vector[dim][30];
```

No se suele usar los VLA por problemas de portabilidad, no todos los compiladores lo admiten y además es propenso a que ocurra desbordamiento de pila.

Para estar mas seguro, deberías usar una [matriz dinámica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376010/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-realmente-los-arrays-bidimensionales-din%C3%A1micos-en-c/376118#376118).

**3.-** La función [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) no limpia el búfer `stdin`, sino el `stdout`:

```c
fflush(stdin);
```

Por mas que funcione en algunas plataformas, no lo deberías usar. Como dice el viejo refrán: **Más vale prevenir que lamentar**.

En este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233445/diferencias-entre-limpiar-el-b%C3%BAfer-en-c) puedes ver como se limpia el búfer `stdin` de una manera estándar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda muy valiosa ! me hice lio al pepe. Gracias  !

Comment: @JuanJ Puedes agradecer [aceptando la respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427/c%C3%B3mo-funciona-la-aceptaci%C3%B3n-de-respuestas#:~:text=Para%20marcar%20una%20respuesta%20como,la%20respuesta%2C%20en%20cualquier%20momento.) que resolvio tu problema.