# Llenar arreglo de caracteres en C

Tags: array, c, bucle-for

estoy presentando problemas a la hora de entender como llenar un arreglo de caracteres en C e imprimir esos datos ingresados, me gustaría saber cual es la forma adecuada de trabajarlo ya que a la hora de compilar solo me arroja un solo elemento del arreglo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {            
    char nombre[30];
    int i = 0;
                        
    printf("\t\t------------FishCool Enterprises--------------\n");
    printf("\n\tBienvenido Usuario a continuacion se le pedira que ingrese los nombres de los empleados activos");

    while (i < 3){
        printf("\nIngrese el nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", &nombre);
        i++;
    }
                    
    printf("Los nombres ingresados son %s", nombre);
}
```

Comment: lo que tu conoces como string en C no existe, un *string* es un array de caracteres, por ejempl, si tienes `char name = "christian"` la variable `nombre` es un array. Lo que en realidad guardas en tu variable `nombre` es un array por lo que al final tienes un array de arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta declaración:

```c
char nombre[30];
```

Le indica al compilador: *"Oye, reserva memoria para un array de 30 elementos"*. Lo que pasa es que en ese *array* solo puedes almacenar únicamente un nombre. El *array* puede estar reflejado así en memoria:

```c
------ Array "nombre" -------
0x0A | 0x0B  | 0x0C | 0x0D   ... | N direcciones
J       U       A      N     ... | data..
```

Como podrás ver, en cada dirección de memoria se guarda un *caracter* de algún nombre, por lo que un simple **array unidimensional** no es suficiente en este caso, ¡necesitas un **array bidimensional**!

Si sabemos la cantidad de empleados, podemos usar un array bidimensional con tamaño estático:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{         
    //Acá podremos almacenar 100 nombres de empleados pero la longitud del nombre del empleado debe ser hasta 30 caracteres...
    char nombres[100][30];
    int i = 0;
                       
    printf("\t\t------------FishCool Enterprises--------------\n");
    printf("\n\tBienvenido Usuario a continuacion se le pedira que ingrese los nombres de los empleados activos");

    while (i < 3)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese el nombre: ");
        scanf("%s", nombres[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
    i = 0; //Rayos... otra vez debo volver a inicializar esta variable, que pasa si me olvido?
    //Imprimimos los nombres...
    while(i < 3)
    {
        printf("%s\n", nombres[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

### Observaciones

**1.** Si vas a usar la función `scanf` para leer cadenas, al menos debes especificar el tamaño del array para evitar un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://www.veracode.com/security/buffer-overflow).

Ejemplo:

```c
scanf("%29s", nombres[i]);
```

Puedes encontrar mas información en este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383852/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-un-desbordamiento-de-b%C3%BAfer-cuando-se-pide-una-cadena-con-scanf).

O también puedes usar la función [fgets](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), es útil cuando los nombres tienen espacio.

**2.** Trata de minimizar el ciclo de vida de las variables (en tu caso, es la variable `i`), de este modo no necesitarás volver a inicializar la variable cuando la necesites usar.

Por ejemplo:

```c
int main() 
{         
    char nombres[100][30];
                 
    printf("\t\t------------FishCool Enterprises--------------\n");
    printf("\n\tBienvenido Usuario a continuacion se le pedira que ingrese los nombres de los empleados activos");
    
    //La variable "i" solo es visible en este for..
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("\nIngrese el nombre: ");
        scanf("%29s", nombre[i]);
    }
    
    //La variable "i" solo es visible en este for..
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", nombre[i]);
    }
}
```

### Nota

Si necesitas un array bidimensional cuyo tamaño debe ser dinámico, este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376010/c%C3%B3mo-funcionan-realmente-los-arrays-bidimensionales-din%C3%A1micos-en-c) te puede servir.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder mostrar todos los nombres deberías hacer un bucle:

```
printf("Los nombres ingresados son:");
for(int i = 0, i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s", nombre[i]);
    i++;
}
```